# Quadratic curve not rendered correctly on different devices

Tags: swift, drawing, bezier, quadratic-curve

I'm trying to draw a bezier path with a quadratic curve in the middle. The curve works well on iPhone 8 and XS, but is not responsive (i.e. not rendered correctly) on other devices.

Below is the image of the curve in iPhone XS (correct)

[image]

and iPhone XR (incorrect)

[image]

I've tried to use the view's constraint to get the middle value of the line but somehow it still not working

Here is the code where i'm drawing the path:

```
//self.viewTabBorder is the grey line, which is a uiview with 1 pixel height
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: self.viewTabBorder.center.x - self.btnHome.frame.width + 20, y: 0))
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: self.viewTabBorder.center.x + self.btnHome.frame.size.width - 20, y: 0), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: self.viewTabBorder.center.x, y: self.btnHome.frame.height + 5))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.viewTabBorder.center.x + self.btnHome.frame.size.width - 20, y: 0))

        let line = CAShapeLayer()
        line.path = path.cgPath
        line.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 224, green: 224, blue: 224).cgColor
        line.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(line)
        self.viewTabBorder.layer.addSublayer(line)
    }
```

Can anyone show me what i'm missing? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Upload a screen shot of the profiler, otherwise people have nothing to work off of

Comment: @Alexander sorry i'm still new to swift. Can you show me what exactly a profiler is?

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/397-instruments-tutorial-with-swift-getting-started

Comment: @Alexander thank you for the link. Below is the link of the screenshot of the profiler  that i just took:
https://imgur.com/a/Bx9c8WA

Comment: Investigate what caused that CPU spike

Comment: So there are two methods which is causing the CPU spike:
1/ AppDelegate: i'm checking some user permission here with promisekit.
2/ A method that is "not in a known library range and cannot be symbolicated", so it returns "not available" when i try to investigate more
https://imgur.com/a/gG7kS3f

Comment: I can't help much here, but I think that should be enough info to give some leads to potential answerers. Edit your post and detail everything you just commented, including in-line screen shots

Comment: When you say “not responsive”, are you saying that it’s slow? Or are you saying “responsive” in the web designer sense, that it’s not adapting to the different screen sizes appropriately? I’m assuming you meant the latter (which is an issue here, which I’ve answered below, regardless to any performance concerns you might have), not the former.

Comment: Unrelated, but when you override any of these view lifecycle methods, it’s prudent to always call the `super` implementation, too.

Comment: @Rob sorry if my English confused you. My "responsive" here means the responsive in web design sense.

Comment: No worries. I suspected that’s what you meant. Hopefully my answer below addresses your issue. It’s simply that this discussion w Alexander regarding Instruments graphs was obviously predicated on the assumption that you were concerned about the speed/performance of the app and has nothing to do with your question here. ;)

Comment: Thank you for editing my question and the answer below. I'll be working on it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of observations:

1. You are defining paths for sublayers to views. Doing this in `viewWillAppear` is too early in the process. The layout engine may not be done applying constraints, placing the views in their final location. Do the defining of the paths in [`viewDidLayoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621398-viewdidlayoutsubviews), not in `viewWillAppear` (nor `viewDidLoad`, nor `viewWillLayoutSubviews`).

   This also has the virtue that should you ever change your app to support multiple orientations or do any changes that affect the constraints in the view, this `viewDidLayoutSubviews` we be called again so these sublayers will be properly updated as needed. If you use `viewWillAppear` your app will not support dynamic changes to your views (should you ever need that).
2. That having been said, be aware that `viewDidLayoutSubviews` can be called multiple times. So you can, for example, add the sublayers in `viewDidLoad`, but update their paths in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.
3. It is likely not an issue here, but I would suggest you avoid using `frame` or `center` when defining a path for a sublayer. Remember that these two properties are defined in the coordinate system of their *superview.* I’d suggest you always use a view’s `bounds` (defined in a view’s own coordinate system), not its `frame` (defined in its superview’s coordinate system) when trying to define a path for a sublayer. And if you want, for example, the horizontal center of a view when defining a sublayer’s path, use `bounds.midX` not `center.x`.

   Sometimes this won’t matter (if the view goes edge-to-edge within its superview), but (a) it suggests a misunderstanding of the different coordinate systems; and (b) if you ever add safe areas or otherwise adjust the placement of the view, using the `frame`/`center` will get you into trouble.

---

A slightly more advanced concept: Once you have your immediate issue behind you, you might consider moving this configuration of subviews into a `UIView` subclass (using its `layoutSubviews` method), possibly even making it an `@IBDesignable` class so you can see this rendered in Interface Builder. Or, another approach is to wrap this in a container view controller. But either way, this can help prevent view controller “bloat”. It’s probably a bit beyond the scope of this question, but something to consider as you move forward.

Comment: Thank you for a very thorough explanation. Solved the problem by doing the steps as you instructed! I will also try other concepts that you suggest. Totally saved my day